# AHK COM Passing Variable through File Path when saving

Tags: com, autohotkey

I would like the file to save as using the variable STYLE which the user enters at the beginning.

I also need help sending the data to a printer with variable amount of copies.

From here on is where I need help:

```
ComObjActive("Word.Application").ActiveDocument.SaveAs("L:\10. 2016\TKT Issued\"%Style%")
```

Please look at the below code for what I already have.

```
#NoEnv  ; Recommended for performance and compatibility with future AutoHotkey releases.
; #Warn  ; Enable warnings to assist with detecting common errors.
SendMode Input  ; Recommended for new scripts due to its superior speed and reliability.
SetWorkingDir %A_ScriptDir%  ; Ensures a consistent starting directory.

F12::
Gui, Add, Text,, Please enter Style:
Gui, Add, Edit, vStyle
Gui, Add, Text,, Please enter Price:
Gui, Add, Edit, vPrice
Gui, Add, Text,, Please enter Docket Number:
Gui, Add, Edit, vDocket
Gui, Add, Text,, Please enter Page Quantity:
Gui, Add, Edit, vPages
Gui, Add, Button, default, OK
Gui, Show,, Cutting Ticket Producer
return


GuiClose:
ButtonOK:
Gui, Submit
MsgBox You entered Style: %Style%, Price: %Price%, Docket Number: %Docket% and%Pages% Pages. Data will be sent to printer.


MSWordMultiReplace("STYLE",Style, "PRICE", Price, "DKT", Docket)    

MSWordMultiReplace(params*) {   ; by Learning one

    oWord  :=  ComObjCreate("Word.Application")
    a:="L:\10. 2016\TKT Issued\TEMPLATE.doc"
    oWord.Documents.Open(a)
    oWord.Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
    oWord.Selection.Find.Replacement.ClearFormatting    
    For k,v in Params
    {
        c++
        if (c = 1)
        {
            st := v
            continue
        }
        rt := v, c := 0
        oWord.Selection.Find.Execute(st, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, rt, 2)
    }   
ComObjActive("Word.Application").ActiveDocument.SaveAs("L:\10. 2016\TKT Issued\"%Style%")


    ExitApp
}
Reload
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
#NoEnv  ; Recommended for performance and compatibility with future AutoHotkey releases.
; #Warn  ; Enable warnings to assist with detecting common errors.
SendMode Input  ; Recommended for new scripts due to its superior speed and reliability.
SetWorkingDir %A_ScriptDir%  ; Ensures a consistent starting directory.

F12::
Gui, Add, Text,, Please enter Style:
Gui, Add, Edit, vStyle
Gui, Add, Text,, Please enter Price:
Gui, Add, Edit, vPrice
Gui, Add, Text,, Please enter Docket Number:
Gui, Add, Edit, vDocket
Gui, Add, Text,, Please enter Page Quantity:
Gui, Add, Edit, vPages
Gui, Add, Button, default, OK
Gui, Show,, Cutting Ticket Producer
return


GuiClose:
ButtonOK:
Gui, Submit
MsgBox You entered Style: %Style%, Price: %Price%, Docket Number: %Docket% and%Pages% Pages. Data will be sent to printer.


MSWordMultiReplace("STYLE",Style, "PRICE", Price, "DKT", Docket)    

MSWordMultiReplace(params*) {   ; by Learning one

    oWord  :=  ComObjCreate("Word.Application")
    a:="L:\10. 2016\TKT Issued\TEMPLATE.doc"
    oWord.Documents.Open(a)
    oWord.Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
    oWord.Selection.Find.Replacement.ClearFormatting    
    For k,v in Params
    {
        c++
        if (c = 1)
        {
            st := v
            continue
        }
        if (k == 2)
            Style := v

        rt := v, c := 0
        oWord.Selection.Find.Execute(st, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, rt, 2)
    }   
    oWord.ActiveDocument.SaveAs("L:\10. 2016\TKT Issued\" Style)


    ExitApp
}
Reload
```

Comment: For some reason I overlooked the variadic function, edited the answer, let me know if this helped.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. Are you able to help with the print part?

Comment: You are welcome. I suggest you ask a separate question about printing multiple documents and be sure to include any code you have tried.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot access the `Style` variable directly. You have to get it as the second parameter you have passed. See the below code,

```
For k,v in params
{
    if (k = 2)
    {
        fileloc = L:\10. 2016\TKT Issued\%v%
        ComObjActive("Word.Application").ActiveDocument.SaveAs(fileloc)
    }
}
```

this worked for me

Comment: Thank you, this works.

Are you able to advise me on the print part?

Comment: Hi it save the file with a variable name as I wanted, however it is saving the file before making the changes?